# An elegant way of doing this concatenation in TF / Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a tensor tmp1. I want to create tmp2 which is N copies of tmp1 along the first axis of tmp1 (tmp1 has dimensionality of 1 along its first axis).
I did it with a for loop. But I hate them cause they slow down training. Is there a better way of creating tmp2?

```
tmp2 = tf.concat((tmp1, tmp1), axis=1)
for i in range(2*batch_size-2):
    tmp2 = tf.concat((tmp2, tmp1), axis=1)
```

What I have done above is: first intialize tmp2 with two copies of tmp1, then, keep adding more copies along the that axis in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want numpy `repeat()`. Use the `axis` argument to specify which axis to repeat along:

```
In [1]: x = np.random.randint(1, 10, (5,5))                                                                                                                     
In [2]: x                                                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 
array([[7, 3, 6, 8, 8],
       [6, 5, 3, 3, 9],
       [1, 7, 1, 5, 7],
       [4, 6, 6, 8, 3],
       [3, 7, 8, 6, 7]])
In [4]: x.repeat(2, axis=1)                                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: 
array([[7, 7, 3, 3, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9],
       [1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7],
       [4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 7, 7, 8, 8, 6, 6, 7, 7]])
```

Or possibly `numpy.tile()`:

```
In [15]: np.tile(x, 2)                                                                                                                                            
Out[15]: 
array([[7, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 3, 6, 8, 8],
   [6, 5, 3, 3, 9, 6, 5, 3, 3, 9],
   [1, 7, 1, 5, 7, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7],
   [4, 6, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 3],
   [3, 7, 8, 6, 7, 3, 7, 8, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I wanted. Turns out tensorflow has got their own version of it tf.tile. I knew I missed something.

Comment: Unfortuately, tf.tile is not as flexible as repeat cause you cannot dictate the axis of concatenation. You have to do a reshape afterwards.